# How to return table column data type for sorting

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript to generate table and I added a click event to the header tags so user can click a column name to sort but I need now to sort the column in the `dataset` so I need to know the name of the column and the datatype to pass to the function `sort_col()` whether it is string or number or date to be able to sort based on this datatype so how I can do that ?

```js
var dataset  = [ 
  { "field1":"dfg34r", "field2":"32.24" },
  { "field1":"d3f32dg", "field2":"32.52", "fdate":"3/2/2015" },
  { "field1":"fdbhjjts", "fdate":"7/4/2015" } ] ;
var cols = [];

function addHeaders(table, keys) {
  var row = table.insertRow();
  
    for( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();
   
      cols.push(keys[i]);
      cell.outerHTML = "<th><a href='#'>"+keys[i]+"</a></th>";
  }
}

var max_keys = 0;
var max_idx = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++ ) {

  var child = dataset[i];
      
  cur_keys = Object.keys(child).length;
  if (cur_keys > max_keys) {
      max_keys = cur_keys;
      max_idx = i;
  }
      
}

var table = document.createElement('table');
addHeaders(table, Object.keys(dataset[max_idx]));

for( var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++ ) {

  var child = dataset[i];
 
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var col_idx = 0;
  
  Object.keys(child).forEach(function(k) {
    
    if (k != cols[col_idx]){
        var cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
    }
        
    col_idx++;    
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(child[k]));

  })
}

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(table);

var th = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for (i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
        th[i].addEventListener("click", sort_col);
}

function sort_col(){
  alert(this.innerHTML);
  
    
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="text-align: left;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What assumptions can you make about your different data types?

Write a function to help you choose a comparator, here is an example of what such a function could look like

```
function chooseSortType(exampleData) {
    let choice = typeof exampleData;

    if (choice === 'object') {
        const type = [Date, Array, Foo, ...]
            .find(objType => exampleData instanceof objType);
        if (type) choice = type.constructor.name;
    }

    if (choice === 'string') {
        // test against RegExps to match types, e.g.
        if (/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\d{2}?$/.test(exampleData))
            choice = 'stringDate';
        else if (false)
            ; // etc
    }

    const known = {
        number(x, y) {
            return y - x;
        },
        string(x, y) {
            return x.localeCompare(y);
        },
        Date(x, y) {
            return y.valueOf() - x.valueOf();
        },
        Array(x, y) {
            return y.length - x.length;
        },
        stringDate(x, y) {
            x = new Date(x);
            y = new Date(y);
            return y.valueOf() - x.valueOf();
        }
    };
    return known[choice];
}
```

Now say you want to sort an Array but you don't know what type you'll be wanting to sort by, you pass in an example of the data to sort by and the function selects the correct comparator

```
let arr = [[3, 3, 3], [1], [4, 4, 4, 4], [2, 2]];
arr.sort(chooseSortType(arr[0]));
// `arr` now [Array[1], Array[2], Array[3], Array[4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to see the column that was clicked...

```
for (i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
    th[i].addEventListener("click", function (evt) {sort_col(evt);)};
}
```

and this to get the column name

```
function sort_col(evt) {

    alert(evt.target.innerText);
}
```